# Google Maps - Setting an address onLoad

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am new to Google Maps API and I have the Google Map below working. However, I am having a hard time understanding how to set an address. I have 2,000 entries that each include an address stored in a database and I have all the data needed to 'set' the address for the map onLoad of the description page, given the opportunity. However, I am not sure how to do this. I was wondering if someone can show me a basic example of setting the address, city, state, zip and then having a marker on the map as well.

In addition, I am confused as to, if I have all the components of the address separated, I am not required to geocode, correct? Doesn't geocode just make it easy to create a map from an unparsed / long address string and puts a limitation on the number of times you can request a geocode? In other words, if I have all the address components (such as zip, city, state, address, etc) stored in a DB, then can't I set an address without being constrained by google maps geocoding limitations?

Following address:

`123 Flower Street, Miami, Florida 32826`

My JS so far...

```
   function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
            zoom: 8,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

I appreciate any suggestions!

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for geocoding: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/

Here you have code which query google for a location of your address and then point a marker on received position:

```
  function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
      zoom: 8,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
        mapOptions);
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': "123 Flower Street, Miami, Florida 32826" }, function (results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        map: map,
                        position: results[0].geometry.location,
                    });
                } else 
                  alert("Problem with geolocation");

      });
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: +1, This worked! Thanks for the reply! Is there a way to set an address without using a `geocoder` to avoid the 2,500/day request constraint?

Comment: The only think you can do is to statically set the coordinates of every marker, however this would work only if you have a set of fixed addresses.

Comment: The request quota using the API geocoder is per client.  If you think that will be a problem, then you should geocode the addresses offline and use the coordinates to show the marker on page load.  See [this article in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geocodestrat) for more information on geocoding strategies.